# How to enable List Pricing buttons

Tags: sitecore-commerce

How can we enable List Pricing buttons in Sitecore Commerce business tool? In the image below, we can see the buttons disabled.

How can we enable these buttons?
[image: List Pricing]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try adding a new entity version.
Go to summary section, select arrow at right and from drop down click on "Add Entity Version".
[image]

And from Entity Versions section select the new version created.